# NSThread.isFinished is the strict opposite to NSThread.isExecuting?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Are there any subtle differences?

Are we sure that in both cases ([NSThread isFinished] == YES, [NSThread isExecuting] == NO), the thread doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: I'm not sure about NSThread but with NSOperation you can have cases where both are false since the operation has not started yet. I guess that you could have the same case with a thread. Also, I'm not sure what would happen if you sleep a thread.

Comment: There's another option where [NSThread isCancelled] == YES, [NSThread isFinished] == NO.
The whole reference is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsthread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)